# ASP.NET MVC 3 Labels Not Displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class marked as follows:

```
public class MyClass{
    [Display(Name="First Name")]
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
}
```

In the Razor view I am accessing it like so, where MyClass is a property  on the model:

```
 @Html.Label("MyClass.FirstName")
```

However the value defined in the Display attribute isn't displayed. If I write:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyClass.FirstName)
```

This works fine, however for the solution I am working on I have to use the first method. What have I missed on the first method?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for looking at this question, the problem was caused by the model be altered before the partial view was called. This mean that the model being evaluated against was not the model I was expecting.

The problem is now resolved.

Comment: please post the code for your entire view. I don't see where the @model include is

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.Label("Model.MyClass.FirstName")`?

Comment: is it a typo in your question above that you have the parameter in the first method in double quotes?   Shouldn't it be model.MyClass.FirstName without any quotations around it?

Comment: It should just be @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.PropertyOfModel)

Comment: Also make sure your model's namespace is in scope

Comment: Which is why we asked for the whole view :) LOL

Answer (score 1):

If you are strongly typing your view with the `MyClass` model try

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is an example from one of my projects.
```

First the view model class

```
  public class UsersRegisterViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "E-Mail Address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "E-Mail address is required")]
        [Email(ErrorMessage = "Not a valid e-mail address")]
        [Remote("UserNameIsAvailable", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "Username is not available")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Verify Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please confirm your password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords don't match")]
        public string VerifyPassword { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a display name")]
        [Remote("DisplayNameIsAvailable", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "Display name is not avalable")]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }

Now the View (Ignore the AJAX goo)

    @model UsersRegisterViewModel


<div id="user-register" class="site-contol">
    <h2>Account Registration</h2>
    <p></p>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Users", null, new AjaxOptions
                                                                         {
                                                                             HttpMethod = "post",
                                                                             UpdateTargetId = "user-registration",
                                                                             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                                             OnSuccess = "registrationCallBacks.onSuccess",
                                                                             OnFailure = "registrationCallBacks.onError"
                                                                         }, new {@id = "frm-sign-in"}))
    {
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)</li>
            <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)&nbsp;@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)</li>
            <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)</li>
            <li>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)&nbsp;@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)</li>
            <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.VerifyPassword)</li>
            <li>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.VerifyPassword)&nbsp;@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VerifyPassword)</li>
            <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.DisplayName)</li>
            <li>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DisplayName)&nbsp;@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DisplayName)</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="submit" name="sb-register" value="Create Account"/></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```